# Trying to update Bitmap every 100 milliseconds

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I'm trying to change the color of a single pixel on a random walk every 100 milliseconds in a bitmap. This is my code but after I click the button which is supposed to trigger the code, all I see is a sudden change to the bitmap I'm trying to update rather than seeing the change happen in real time every 100 ms.

How do I make the Bitmap update every 100 ms, in real time, rather than just showing what's been changed when I click the button?

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int height;
    private int width;
    Bitmap image;

    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bitmap_imageview);
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        image.eraseColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.verydarkblue));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        Button press = (Button) findViewById(R.id.press);

        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        width = image.getWidth() / 4;
        height = image.getHeight() / 3;
        image.setPixel(width, height, getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        press.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateImage);
                mHandler.postDelayed(updateImage, 1000);
            }
        });

    }


    private Runnable updateImage = new Runnable() {
        final Random random = new Random();
        public void run() {

            image.setPixel(width, height, getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            int widthIncrement = random.nextInt(3) - 1;
            int heightIncrement = random.nextInt(3) - 1;
            height = height + heightIncrement;
            width = width + widthIncrement;
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: How do I make the change happen in real time?

Comment: Consider using a background Thread in image manipulation then return it in the Main UIThread. You need also to consider that your image manipulation might have a delays if it is really huge and how complex the changes is, so your 100ms might not be an enough time. Note: doing an image manipulation on UI Thread might result to framerate drop.

Comment: What do you mean by "return it to the main uithread"?